# STL's vector resizing

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I can't find this piece of information. I'm dealing with an odd situation here where i'm inside of a loop and i can get a random information at any given time. This information has to be stored in a vector. Now each frame i have to set this vector to ensure that i won't exeed the space (i'm writing values into random points in the vector using indexing).

Now assuming there's no way to change this piece of code, i want to know, does the vector "ignore" the resize() function if i send an argument that's exactly the size of the vector? Where can i find this information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From MSDN reference[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wezs0zy6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> If the container's size is less than the requested size, _Newsize, elements are added to the vector until it reaches the requested size. If the container's size is larger than the requested size, the elements closest to the end of the container are deleted until the container reaches the size _Newsize. If the present size of the container is the same as the requested size, **no action is taken**

The ISO C++ standard *(page 485 [2](http://www-d0.fnal.gov/~dladams/cxx_standard.pdf))* specifies this behaviour for `vector::resize`

```
void resize ( size_type sz , T c = T ());

if ( sz > size ())
  insert ( end () , sz - size () , c );
else if ( sz < size ())
  erase ( begin ()+ sz , end ());
else
; // Does nothing
```

So yes, the vector ignores it and you don't need to perform a check on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda-sorta.

Simply resizing a vector with resize() can only result in more memory being used by the vector itself (will change how much is used by its elements).  If there's not enough room in the reserved space, it will reallocate (and sometimes they like to pad themselves a bit so even if there is you might grow).  If there is already plenty of room for the requested size and whatever padding it wants to do, it will not regrow.

When the specification says that the elements past the end of the size will be deleted, it means *in place*.  Basically it will call _M_buff[i].~T() for each element it is deleting.  Thus any memory your object *allocates* will be deleted, assuming a working destructor, but the space that the object itself occupies (it's size) will not be.  The vector will grow, and grow, and grow to the maximum size you ever tell it to and will not reshrink while it exists.